# Java FileOutputStream save the filename with other charset in system

Tags: java, file-io, unicode

I'm having trouble with the filename charset when I use FileOutputStream.

My code is very simple, and use

```
FileOutputStream
```

With a `File` Object as parameter.

But in my application, the path file is correct printed on `System.out.println()` call.

But on disk, it's saved using another charset (I don't know what is).

For example: On `System.out.println` the out is:

`C:\Folder\MyLatinNameWithÇorÃorAnotheLatinChar`

But in real disk filename the name writed is:

`C:\Folder\MyLatinNameWithÃ§orÃ£orAnotheLatinChar`

What is happening?

Sorry about noob question, but I'm really have problem with this.

Comment: Seems like you might not be specifying the code set correctly while writing to file. Show us the code to write in file.

Comment: I try adding this code: `File storeFile = new File(filePath); InputStream fileContent = item.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(storeFile);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768]; //36kb
                    while(fileContent.read(buffer) > 0){
                        outputStream.write(buffer);
                    }`

Comment: It's an interesting question. The Java API isn't clear on this point. This is **not** related to the character encoding used to write the file - FileOutputStream doesn't even have one, only OutputStreamWriter has one. It is important to know which file system on Windows you are using, but I would guess that it's an NTFS filesystem, which stores file names in UTF16.

Comment: I'm using windows with NTFS file system..

Comment: my bad i didn't realized that it was the problem with file name and not the content. Sorry for any confusion it might have created.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is not very trustworthy.

It would be better to inspect the string directly to see if it is correct:

```
  private static void debugPrint(String str) {
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
      if (ch < ' ' || ch > '~') {
        System.out.format("\\u%04x", (int) ch);
      } else {
        System.out.print(ch);
      }
    }
  }
```

It'll print the escape form of anything outside the visible ASCII range - Ç becomes `\u007c`. You can then check [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) values against [the charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) to see what is really in the string.

---

The trouble here probably extends from the number of character encodings in play in Windows:

- ["OEM"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964655) (predates Windows) - default in cmd.exe
- ["ANSI"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964654) (introduced with Windows) - default in Notepad
- "Unicode" (UTF-16LE - adoption prevalent via Windows NT line)

All but Unicode are deprecated and everything else hangs around for backwards compatibility reasons but to routinely corrupt data for the unwary. When Java was introduced Unicode adoption was not widespread and [ANSI default platform encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) persist on Windows.

It would also be an idea to check the [system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29). Some devrlopers feed in a `file.encoding` property but changing this from the default is [not supported](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515) and it might adversely affect native code calls.